# Office Open XML - Freeze panes in Excel

Tags: excel, datatables, openxml

I use datatables and generate an Excel file, with customizations of the output. See fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/uo867xbm/

in the row 19 I append the  part to freeze the header and the first column :

`var freezePanes = '<sheetViews><sheetView tabSelected="1" workbookViewId="0"><pane xSplit="1" ySplit="1" topLeftCell="B2" activePane="bottomRight" state="frozen"/></sheetView></sheetViews>';`

This works great when opening the file in LibreOffice but Excel says that the file is damaged. The  part seems conform to the OpenXML standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel is fussy about the order of elements in the XML. In your file you have `cols` and `sheetData` before `sheetViews` but according to the [ECMA spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-376/) `sheetViews` should be before the other two:

```
<xsd:complexType name="CT_Worksheet">
    <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="sheetPr" type="CT_SheetPr" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:element name="dimension" type="CT_SheetDimension" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:element name="sheetViews" type="CT_SheetViews" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:element name="sheetFormatPr" type="CT_SheetFormatPr" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:element name="cols" type="CT_Cols" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    <xsd:element name="sheetData" type="CT_SheetData" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
```

It looks like you have a similar issue with your fonts. The expected order there (for the elements you have) is `name`, `color` then `sz` but you have `sz`, `name` then `color`.

Comment: this is correct, many thanks!! new fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/30be68fm/ ; would you please mind posting your comment as a response so that I can mark it as the accepted answer

Comment: Glad it works @laloune, happy to help. I'm slightly confused though, what else did you want me to post?

Comment: oh sorry, I did not notice that it was already an answer. I just accepted the answer ;) thanks again !